# How to deliver a click with modifier keys via Selenium's WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I've got this line of code:

```
final WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
```

Now, how to I click on that button with the meta key held down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per Madd0g, java code would look like this:

```
  Actions shiftClick = new Actions(driver);
  shiftClick.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(element).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

Answer (score 13):

hmm.. I'm not exactly sure about java, but in C# this is done with the ActionBuilder --

```
new Actions(Browser).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(element).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Perform();
```

Comment: Yep, that did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions.

```
 final WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    if (ctrlKey) {
        actions = actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
    }
    if (altKey) {
        actions = actions.keyDown(Keys.ALT);
    }
    if (shiftKey) {
        actions = actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT);
    }
    actions = actions.click(button);
```

Now, if only it actually worked.

Comment: is there no `perform()` method? I think there should be. Also, I believe you're responsible for releasing the modifier key (so you'll also need `keyUp()`)

Comment: There are clearly issues with the drivers for FF8 and Chrome, which is what I'm working against.

Comment: are you using the latest version of webdriver? FF8 support is pretty recent